# Is there any other way to prevent an object of a class from being generated in Java?

Tags: java

sorry for asking a very ignorant question. Despite my research, I couldn't find any results. As it is known, when we make the constructor methods private, we cannot create the object of that class.

```
public class Person{
 private Person(){}
}
```

Is there any other method other than this?

Comment: If you make a constructor private it doesn't mean you can't create an instance of that class: you can do it in the class itself. What do you need exactly?

Comment: You're right. I forgot it. I want to make sure that the new word cannot be used.

Comment: What do you mean with ```the new word cannot be used```?

Comment: I want it to be impossible to create objects. Sorry my english is a bit bad.

Comment: @harbk you mean like making it abstract or making sure only its static methods can be called?

Comment: new Person(); I just want to prevent it from happening.

Comment: @harbk then making the constructor `private` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Making it `private` is the only way to prevent anyone from writing `new Person()`.

You can do other things to interfere with object construction, such as throwing exceptions in the constructor, but that all takes effect at runtime.

Comment: This answer comes across as ambiguous. For example, a private constructor does not prevent _anyone_ from writing `new Person()` - specifically, you yourself can still write it ('you' being: The person currently responsible for maintaining the Person.java source file), also, reflection can still be used to make instances if that's relevant.